# Parse user-input concerning search criteria

Tags: java, search, parsing, user-input

I'm looking for a way to parse some user-input. The input should show which searches have to be performed and how they have to be combined.

- 1 AND 2
- (3 AND 2) OR 1
- (3 AND 2) OR (1 AND 4)
- ( (3 OR 4) AND 1) OR 2
- etc.

The first example should combine the results of search 1 and 2 in an AND-fashion. The second example should combine the results of search 3 and 2 in an AND-fashion, and combine the results of this combination to the results of search 1 in an OR-fashion. Etc.

Any ideas on how to do this?

Answer (score 2):

Think of your 'result' as an Object that offers methods for and and or like in the following interface:

```
public interface AndOrCapable<T> {
  public T and(T anOtherResult);
  public T or(T anOtherResult);
}
```

Then you can translate your user input into something like:

```
Result total = r2.or(r1.and(r3.or(r4))); // your fourth example
```

This is just to clarify the concept - in your case you need a dynamic evaluator because you use user input.

So you still need a validator/parser to transform the user input into an (syntax) tree, which will be the model you'd use to calculate the total.

Hope it helped a bit!

Answer (score 2):

JavaCC is a good tool to use to generate a parser for this.  Alternately, if you can change the syntax a little you may be able to the scripting facilities with java using a scheme interpreter, e.g.

```
( (3 OR 4) AND 1) OR 2
```

becomes

```
(OR (AND (OR 3 4) 1) 2)
```

Then you just need to implement the AND/OR

Answer (score 1):

Just some inspiration on how to create parsers for generic keyword search ...

Even though you tagged the question *java*, here's an example of a searchparser in python. It uses pyparsing, a parser generator, which takes a grammar and creates code, which can be run to parser user input.

[https://github.com/pyparsing/pyparsing/blob/master/examples/searchparser.py](http://pyparsing.wikispaces.com/file/view/searchparser.py)

293 lines of code, including a test suite. Maybe it helps you as a starting point ...

Comment: Although it's 'not helpful' for the question, the answer is to good you shouldn't loose reputation for it. I suggest marking the answer Community Wiki, so it doesn't count. (BTW - wasn't me downvoting the answer)

Comment: Pyparsing is no longer hosted on wikispaces.com. Go to https://github.com/pyparsing/pyparsing

Answer (score 1):

The clean solution would be to write an **infix parser**; there are quite a few code examples online. In your example, a simpler algorithm might suffice, however, since you do not need operator precedence etc.

As a coding remark: The `StreamTokenizer` class might help you in parsing the input string.

Answer (score 1):

On the implementation end (once you have a parser, organizing and performing searches):

1. What about creating a `Condition` tree, where `Condition` objects may be simple conditions, or compound conditions joining 2 simple conditions with a boolean (IE `ANDCondition` parent node with children `RangeCondition` and `EqualsCondition`).

   Then you evaluate the top of the tree against each item. This solution is O(mn), where m is number of conditions, and n is number of of items to search, but you can optimize this by removing redundant conditions. It is much faster if the first condition eliminates most items.
2. Version 2: assign a unique key to each item (say, an array index), and perform the searches for each condition, building a `HashSet<Key>` for each condition.  Then, starting with the smallest set of *required* keys, remove or add keys for each condition until you have final results.  This may be faster than the above, depending.

Note: these approaches mimic how an SQL Database will operate -- if your system is sufficiently large or complex, you should probably investigate using a database instead of writing your own code to do the same thing.